# Pipe output to use as the search specification for grep on Linux

Tags: linux, grep

How do I pipe the output of grep as the search pattern for another grep?

As an example:

```
grep <Search_term> <file1> | xargs grep <file2>
```

I want the output of the first grep as the search term for the second grep. The above command is treating the output of the first grep as the file name for the second grep. I tried using the `-e` option for the second grep, but it does not work either.

Comment: Related: *[Read expression for grep from standard input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641731)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If using Bash then you can use backticks:

```
> grep -e "`grep ... ...`" files
```

the `-e` flag and the double quotes are there to ensure that any output from the initial `grep` that starts with a hyphen isn't then interpreted as an option to the second `grep`.

Note that the double quoting trick (which also ensures that the output from grep is treated as a single parameter) only works with Bash.  It doesn't appear to work with (t)csh.

Note also that backticks are the standard way to get the output from one program into the parameter list of another.  Not all programs have a convenient way to read parameters from stdin the way that (f)grep does.

Comment: This one might have a problem if the first grep returns more than one result.

Comment: I tried the solution, it works. Thanks for providing it.

Answer (score 19):

You need to use `xargs`'s `-i` switch:

```
grep ... | xargs -ifoo grep foo file_in_which_to_search
```

This takes the option after `-i` (`foo` in this case) and replaces every occurrence of it in the command with the output of the first `grep`.

This is the same as:

```
grep `grep ...` file_in_which_to_search
```

Comment: xargs replstr option uses a capital -I on OS X

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
grep ... | fgrep -f - file1 file2 ...
```

Comment: It uses the output of the first grep as the grep pattern for the second grep, as the question asked.

Comment: @Nathan, it uses the output of the first grep as the input file of patterns for fgrep.  "-f -" is the normal way of telling a unix program to use standard input as the input file if it normally takes an input file.  Traditionally fgrep was the only grep that took a file as input, although it's possible that Gnu has modified the other greps.

Comment: oh... I missed the standalone "`-`".  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to search for text in files (using grep) that had a certain pattern in their file names (found using find) in the current directory. I used the following command:

```
 grep -i "pattern1" $(find . -name "pattern2")
```

Here *pattern2* is the pattern in the file names and *pattern1* is the pattern searched for
within files matching *pattern2*.

**edit:** Not strictly piping but still related and quite useful...

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use to search for a file from a listing:

```
ls -la | grep 'file-in-which-to-search'
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay breaking the rules as this isn't an answer, just a note that I can't get any of these solutions to work.

```
% fgrep -f test file
```

works fine.

```
% cat test | fgrep -f - file
fgrep: -: No such file or directory
```

fails.

```
% cat test | xargs -ifoo grep foo file 
xargs: illegal option -- i
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]
```

fails.  Note that a capital I is necessary.  If i use that all is good.

```
% grep "`cat test`" file
```

kinda works in that it returns a line for the terms that match but it also returns a line `grep: line 3 in test: No such file or directory` for each file that doesn't find a match.

Am I missing something or is this just differences in my Darwin distribution or bash shell?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this way , and it works great.

```
[opuser@vjmachine abc]$ cat a
not problem
all
problem
first
not to get
read problem
read not problem

[opuser@vjmachine abc]$ cat b
not problem xxy
problem abcd
read problem werwer
read not problem  98989
123 not problem 345
345 problem tyu

[opuser@vjmachine abc]$ grep -e "`grep problem a`" b --col
not problem xxy
problem abcd
read problem werwer
read not problem  98989
123 not problem 345
345 problem tyu

[opuser@vjmachine abc]$
```

Answer (score 0):

You should grep in such a way, to extract filenames only, see the parameter -l (the lowercase L):

```
grep -l someSearch * | xargs grep otherSearch
```

Because on the simple grep, the output is much more info than file names only. For instance when you do

```
grep someSearch *
```

You will pipe to xargs info like this

```
filename1: blablabla someSearch blablabla something else
filename2: bla someSearch bla otherSearch
...
```

Piping any of above line makes nonsense to pass to xargs.
But when you do grep -l someSearch *, your output will look like this:

```
filename1
filename2
```

Such an output can be passed now to xargs

Answer (score -1):

I have found the following command to work using $() with my first command inside the parenthesis to have the shell execute it first.

```
grep $(dig +short) file
```

I use this to look through files for an IP address when I am given a host name.