# Read expression for grep from standard input

Tags: grep, stdin

How can I make grep read the **expression** from standard input (stdin)?

For example (the following doesn't work):

```
grep -i -f &0 /path/to/text/file < "/regexp/"
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use `-f` with a single dash to denote the standard input:

```
$ echo Content | grep -f - notice.html 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
...
```

Note: This has been tested with GNU grep - I am not sure if it's specified by POSIX.

Comment: @Dor: what about using `-E` for extended expressions? Doesn't that work?

Comment: This works fine on MinGW (Windows) - as long as the free-standing dash is included!

Comment: Actually, I get the expected matches but also false positives from grep that I can not explain. The search specification (from standard input) is a series of numbers (like 1.174500, 45045.367300, 45045.442300, 45045.502500, 45675.290200, 48149.824300, 48149.883600 and 52485.123600) and I use the "-A" and "-B" options for grep: "grep -f -   -A 10 -B 10 <file>". I get false positive matches from places far apart in <file>.

Comment: This probably has been solved a long time ago. If you search for 45045.502500, you do realize the `.` is a character wildcard, don't you?

Comment: Doesn't seem like this works on all, definitely doesn't work on a mac

Comment: @SalmonKiller `grep -f /dev/stdin` may work