# How to grep patterns from stdin

Tags: bash, grep, stdin

I made a Bash script some time ago to find duplicate files `/home/usr/xxx/bin/finddup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=${1:-`pwd`}
FILENAME=`basename $0`
DATETIME=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
TMPFILE=`mktemp /tmp/${FILENAME}.${DATETIME}` || exit 1
find -P $DIR -type f -exec cksum {} \; | sort | tee $TMPFILE | cut -f 1-2 -d ' ' | uniq -d | grep -if - $TMPFILE | sort -nr -t' ' -k2,2 | cut -f 3- -d ' ' | while read line; do ls -lhta "$line"; done
```

But today when I tried to use it again, it didn't work.  The problem seems to be from the `grep -if - $TMPFILE` step where it failed to find lines of duplicated files from `$TMPFILE` with patterns provided from stdin.  I cannot figure out the correct usages of `-` here.  Anyone can enlighten me?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read expression for grep from standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641731/read-expression-for-grep-from-standard-input)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need the `-f -` at all. If you don't specify a file for `grep`, it defaults to reading `stdin`.

EDIT: this answer is incorrect. `-f` instructs `grep` to read patterns from `stdin` instead of the text to search.

Comment: Using `find -P $DIR -type f -exec cksum {} \; | sort | tee $TMPFILE | cut -f 1-2 -d ' ' | uniq -d | grep -i $TMPFILE` does not find the desired rows of duplicate files from `$TMPFILE`.  IIRC, that's why I originally used the `-f -` trick.  But obviously something is wrong now that it no longer works.

Comment: What you've written searches for the pattern `$TMPFILE` (or whatever that variable's value is) in the stream being piped into it. What are you trying to accomplish with that `grep`?

Comment: The duplicate files. It should be obvious from the output of the `uniq -d` step.

Comment: Isn't the output of `uniq -d` a list of duplicate files?

Comment: The output of `uniq -d` contains keys like `1006710111 1496` then I pass that into grep via `-` (stdin) as search patterns.

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. They're not being passed in as search patterns, they're being passed in as text to search in. For example, `echo he | grep hello` finds no match, but `echo hello | grep he` does. If you want to pipe search patterns into grep, I'd recommend using `xargs`.

Comment: Downvote: the purpose of `-f $TMPFILE` is to read a list of patterns from `$TMPFILE`.  It obviosly greps those against standard input.